# Extract Variables From IfStatements in EclipseJDT

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I need to extract variables from expressions like if I have a code:-

```
if ( k < m && x < j )
{
    return l;
}
```

I need to extract k, m , x, j.
I used an object of ASTVisitor class to visit the IfStatements from IfStatments I extracted Expressions now I need to extract the various variables used in this Expression.

How to extract variables from an Expression??

Comment: @Typo I need to fetch a list of variables used in this expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should visit the `SimpleName` nodes and check if they have a variable binding.

Install the [ASTView](https://eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/) plugin to see the AST structure.